.gitignore: I want to create an exclusion for my [Bb]in/ ignore line with no success
I have the following in my .gitignore:
[Bb]in/ # this is line 164

# Allow bin directories and their contents under any artifacts folder
!*/artifacts/[Bb]in
!*/artifacts/[Bb]in/
!*/artifacts/[Bb]in/**
!*/artifacts/
!*/artifacts/**/

Still all files in my /provision/scripts/artifacts/bin folder ignored.
For example if I use:
git check-ignore -v provision/scripts/artifacts/bin/x                                                      

it says
.gitignore:164:[Bb]in/  provision/scripts/artifacts/bin/x 

Question
After a general [Bb]in/ entry in my .gitignore, I want to sill include my artifacts/bin content. What am I missing?

Eclusions are positional, so try (I cannot sorry), rewriting your .gitignore as follow:
!artifacts/[Bb]in/
[Bb]in/

Please, let me know it will work.

You want !**/artifacts/[Bb]in, your artifacts/bin is two levels deep but you only wildcarded for one level and patterns with an internal (or leading) / are anchored at the .gitignore level.
